# How to figure out whether a certain function takes a specific value, if the ranges of variables are known

Tags: functions

I have a function of six variables, a known function, say y= F(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6). I know the ranges of these variables: a1<x1<b1,  a2<x2<b2, a3<x3<b3, a4<x4<b4, a5<x5<b5, a6<x6<b6. Is it possible to figure out whether a certain value of this function is reached for any set of the variables. I suspect that a certain value of y, say y0=10^{-12} can be achieved for at least one set of variables x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6. is it possible to find this set in Mathematica?

Comment: It would help if you give the function and ranges.

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code.

Comment: You could try `ContourPlot` and `Manipulate`. For example, see my answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277272/86543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
Assuming[{a1<x1<b1, ...},
FindInstance[f(x1,...,x6) == desiredValue, {x1,...,x6}]]
```

If you give us your full problem (with details), we can better help you.

Comment: thank you David. This works but takes too much time. Is there a way that I can use to speed up the process?  Can a new command be added to the already existing  ones to achieve this goal?

Comment: @neutrino:  Why oh why do you need a new command??  The several hours it would take you to write and debug the code is MUCH longer than simply typing the above.